# WPF - get button by name in a datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a gridcontrol with three columns, one loads buttons dynamically. This is the relevant code:

```
<dxg:GridColumn Name="BtnColumn" Width="200" AllowEditing="False" AllowColumnFiltering="False" 
AllowSorting="False">

   <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <Button Name="MapButton" Click="MapFieldToDataElement" IsEnabled="False">Map</Button>
     </DataTemplate>
  </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

When I try to access this button in the CS file, I get the error that it doesn't exist in this context. So, for example, at a certain point in the program, I want to enable the button:

```
MapButton.IsEnabled = True;
```

I get the error:

```
The name 'MapButton' does not exist in the current context.
```

Is there a way to do access it by name? Thanks.

Comment: can you post the actual error? Also what is "dxg" ?

Comment: You can create a UserControl containing this button and put it into your DataTemplate. With this way you can access your button easily. This is a way to solve this. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @StealthRabbit I added the error. dxg is a Devexpress/gridcontrol prefix.

Comment: You simply can't as Bulutay implied. In your case, set the IsEnabled-property by binding it to your viewmodel-data. Also your CellTemplate will not work as expected for two reasons a) you attempt to use a non-DX control as an InplaceEdit of a Grid b) it is not named "PART_Editor". You will likely encounter wierd navigation behavior of the grid!

Comment: Thanks for the help, folks. I will look at approaching this a different way.

Comment: I strongly recommend mvvm. Buttons should bind to an icommand ( usually a relaycommand or delegatecommand since these are easier to work with ). An icommand has canexecute which will disable the button if it returns false. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview